# What is this black/brown chunky sludge in my sink?

Tags: plumbing, sink

I woke up this morning to a foul-smelling, black/brown gunk that had appeared in my bathroom sink overnight or the previous day.  It doesn't look like a slimy mold like many questions seem to be, instead it is chunky and seems to have dried up.  There might be food bits in it, which makes me think I might have a backup somewhere from the kitchen sink, but that's nowhere near this one.[image: black-brown sludgy chunky mess in a sink]

Comment: It looks like backup from a toilet.. Be careful with the fumes

Comment: Do you have cast iron drains (as opposed to ABS or PVC plastic)? If so, this might be flaked off corrosion of cast iron drain pipe. Is this stuff gritty?

Comment: It is gritty, but pretty much everything in the (visible) plumbing is plastic of one kind or another

Comment: This may just be loosened deposits from the inside of the under sink trap or the pipe in the wall. I would just pick it out of the lavatory and then see if the drains are clear. Are you sure someone did not use a plunger on this lavatory?

Comment: @JimStewart Yeah.  It's just two of us in the house, and neither of us used a plunger the night it happened.  The sink had been draining fine before this happened, but became clogged when this happened (I tried to rinse it down the drain).  Draino cleared it right up, though.

Answer (score 1):

It is from kitchen sink! I just had the same thing appear in my basement drain!! So relieved when the drain guy came! He said soap scum and grease